# Add an id to table created using WP_List_Table class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can i add an id to table element generate by  WP_List_Table?
by default, the table element create with only a class attribute like that:

```
<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list products"></table>
```

and i want to add an id like that:

```
<table id="some-id" class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list products"></table>
```

Is there any argument in WP_List_Table class that allow me to do that?

Comment: Doesn’t look like this can be achieved directly using any parameter. The [`display`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L1260) method outputs an opening `table` tag with classes only. You would need to create your own class that inherits from this one, and overwrite at least this method with one of your own.

Comment: What do you actually need this for? The manual warns about using this function for your own purposes (it was supposed to be used only internally), and since it outputs the table body with a fixed ID, it should not be used more than once per page to begin with. So why the need for an ID on that table …?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these arguments at your WP_List_Table extended class constructor:

For instance:

```
function __construct( $args ) {
        parent::__construct( array(
            'singular'=> 'wp_review_item', //Singular label
            'plural' => 'wp_review_items', //plural label, also this well be one of the table css class
            'ajax'  => false //We won't support Ajax for this table
        ) );
    }
```

Taken from this Gist by @wturnerharris: https://gist.github.com/wturnerharris/7413971

Another option would be to create a wrapper class for your table and take it from there, just like:

```
<div class="myselector">
    <?php $accessoriesList->display(); ?>
</div>
```